# Nutch 2.x: Passing information from one WebPage to another for indexing with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I'm using Nutch 2.x to crawl a domain where each html page has a link to a pdf document.

1. For each html page, I use a plugin to extract information and add it to the metadata.
2. For each pdf document, the tika parser extracts the text.

What I want to do is to join the data extracted from an html page and the text of the corresponding pdf document and index all of it with elasticsearch.

I thought of doing this when parsing or indexing a pdf by accessing the WebPage of the corresponding html page but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Is this feasible? If not I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem using Nutch 1.x (but working with images), my approach was basically to write a custom `ScoringFilter` that took information from the HTMl and distribute it into the `CrawlDatum` of the outlinks (only for outlinks point out to images, in my case).

In Nutch 2.x things are a bit different, but I think that something similar could be done in the `distributeScoreToOutlinks` method of the `ScoringFilter`. In this case you don't have access to the `WebPage` object of the outlinks, but you have access to the `ScoreDatum` object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I thought of using outlinks as the last option but it turned out to be the way to go :)

For anyone facing the same problem you need to build a custom scoring plugin:

1) In the distributeScoreToOutlinks method of the ScoringFilter you have access to the webpage and you can copy its metadata to the ScoreDatum's Meta of each outlink.

2) In the updateScore method, you have access to the ScoreDatum of each inlink. You can simply check the Meta to find where you stored your data earlier and copy it to the webpage's Metadata.